# Numpy compare values inside to return greater index

Tags: numpy

I have a numpy array and another array:

`[array([-1.67397643, -2.77258872]), array([-1.67397643, -2.77258872]), array([-2.77258872, -1.67397643]), array([-2.77258872, -1.67397643])]`

1. Which index position inside the numpy arrays wins - i.e. `-1.67397643 > -2.77258872` - so the first value would be 0.
2. Final output of the numpy array would be `[0, 0, 1, 1]` (a list is fine too)

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a list of arrays, so I would start by making them a proper `numpy` array:

```
a = [array([-1.67397643, -2.77258872]), array([-1.67397643, -2.77258872]), array([-2.77258872, -1.67397643]), array([-2.77258872, -1.67397643])]
b = np.array(a).T # .T transposes it.
c = b[0] < b[1]
```

c is now an `array([False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)`, and probably serves your purpose. If you must have `[0,0,1,1]` instead, then:

```
d = np.zeros(len(c))
d[c] = 1
```

d is now an `array([ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.])`